How to Hyperparameter Tune without sample Bias?
While searching for ways to fine-tune the hyperparameters (HP) of my models I found out multiple reference to Cross Validation Techniques (K-folds, LPO, OOB.632+) and Ways to Select the Best Hyperparameter Combination (Grid-Search, Random-Search, etc.). Many had said to use Nested Cross Validation techiniques to estimate some quality metric of the model, but no one explained how to choose the hyperparameters that would be used at the final model.
The best I could found was articles approaching nested cross validation (nCV) or even a nCV variant for feature selection, which would present the same problem of model selection. But this approach does not provides a unique set of Hyperparameters, but multiple for each one of the folds created by the CV techniques.
What I tried to think was to use the top best hyperparameter combination for the training set of each fold and consider their average quality metric and their "best combination appearance" rate in some type of voting system to define which combination would be the best, then, estimate the quality metric for the selected hyperparameters using all the test sets, but I'm not sure if this would result on an unbiased HP choice and quality estimation.
Do you have any articles ou explanations that could be helpful?

For example, with K-fold cross-validation, you use the same hyperparameters across every fold (training with these hyperparameters will give different parameters for the model and predictions for the validation sets but that does not matter) so you can get a single aggregate quality estimate for those hyperparameters.  Then do it again with different hyperparameters getting a different quality estimate, etc. Then choose the best performing hyperparameters and retrain on the full training set for your final model.

The purpose of the resampling techniques with holdout method you mentioned are estimating hyper-parameters, i.e., capturing its variation over different splits, along with the generalised performance [1]. Even though, holdout reuse is criticised as "holdout overfitting", recent works shown the resilience of holdout method in repeated procedures [2].
[1] Xu, Y., Goodacre, R. On Splitting Training and Validation Set: A Comparative Study of Cross-Validation, Bootstrap and Systematic Sampling for Estimating the Generalization Performance of Supervised Learning. J. Anal. Test. 2, 249–262 (2018). doi
[2] Generalization in Adaptive Data Analysis and Holdout Reuse,
Dwork et. al. arXiv
